# Execute the break; in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have some code.

Pug:

```
div(data-counter="100")
```

SCSS:

```
$start: 100;
$end: 20;

div:before {
  content: attr(data-counter);
  animation: countdown 10s steps(1, start) forwards;
}

@keyframes countdown {
  @for $i from 1 through $start { 
    @if $i == 50 {
      100% {
        content: 'Stop';
      }
    } @else {
      #{$i}% {
        content: '#{($start - $i)}';
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

The problem is that the counter counts from `100` and when it reaches `50`, the counter would stop - `100% {content: 'Stop'; }` And the animation would end (now it continues `49% {content: '51';} 100% {content: 'Stop';} 51% {content: '49';}`).

**Question:** Is there something like `break;` for scss like in js?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/Pjggbv)

**P.S:** `@break;` does not work as desired.

PPS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693480/212421)

Comment: Don't know why but got your code working with @if $i > 49 instead of equal sign. Maybe someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: hm, really work ... but the compilation is not very beautiful

Comment: I can assume that he does not fall into position 50 and immediately jumps to the next number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer posted on the Russian question you can use SCSS to create the numbers

Demo: https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/mwYKpV

SCSS:

```
@function countdown-numbers($from: 100, $through: 0){
    $str: '';
    @for $i from $from through $through { $str: $str + '#{$i}\A'; }
    @return $str;
}


div {
    line-height: 1.2;
    height: 1.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    &::after {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        // creates 50 numbers 100\A 99\A ... 51\A
        // and add STOP to the string 
        content: countdown-numbers(100, 51) + STOP;
        // run animation in 50 steps (don't count start) 
        animation: countdown 10s steps(50) forwards;       
    }
}
@keyframes countdown {
    to { transform: translateY(calc(1.2em - 100%)) }
}
```

CSS Output (using Autoprefixer):

```
div {
  line-height: 1.2;
  height: 1.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div::after {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  content: "100\a 99\a 98\a 97\a 96\a 95\a 94\a 93\a 92\a 91\a 90\a 89\a 88\a 87\a 86\a 85\a 84\a 83\a 82\a 81\a 80\a 79\a 78\a 77\a 76\a 75\a 74\a 73\a 72\a 71\a 70\a 69\a 68\a 67\a 66\a 65\a 64\a 63\a 62\a 61\a 60\a 59\a 58\a 57\a 56\a 55\a 54\a 53\a 52\a 51\aSTOP";
 -webkit-animation: countdown 5s steps(50) forwards;
         animation: countdown 5s steps(50) forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes countdown {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(1.2em - 100%));
            transform: translateY(calc(1.2em - 100%));
  }
}

@keyframes countdown {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(1.2em - 100%));
            transform: translateY(calc(1.2em - 100%));
  }
}
```